# How to map two symfony form field to one model method?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hi stackexchange users,

I have a data (model) class which has two methods which look like this:

```
 class ContactDetails {

    public function setWebsite($address, $type) {
     //do something...
    }

    public function getWebsite($type) {
     //do something...
    }

 }
```

Now I want to create a form where the user can input a website address and choose a type (e.g. "private" or "business") for the address.

To make this possible I have created a custom form type like this

```
class ContactDetailsType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('type', 'text') //better: choice, but for the sake of demo...
        ->add('website', 'text')
        ;

    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'ContactDetailsType';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'ContactDetails',
        ));
    }
}
```

The controller then looks like this:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    //generate completely new cost unit
    $costunit = new ContactDetails();

    //generate form
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactDetailsType(), $costunit);
    $form->add('save', 'submit');

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //yay!
    }

}
```

This obviously doesn't work, as the form component doesn't know how to map these two fields from the type to the data model class.

Question: What is the best practise to map the data of two fields of a form to one method call in a data model class and vice-versa?

Comment: Where does the method that incorporates both of these fields get called? Might be best to just add both those fields to the entity, (type & address) plus their requisite setters and getters, along with another method that calls a string (or whatever you need) that is a concatenation of both the getters.

Comment: Also - I think you can get away with a '[choice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)' field type for 'type'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your place a i would make both fields virtual in form and then use event listener to set data in entity.

[Info about form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Comment: That was a working solution: Setting both fields with 'mapped' => false and then using a POST_SUBMIT event listener to write the values into the model data.